# How to use server time in views when retrieving data from different timezone?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have set a timezone in America in settings.py.  All data are set in American Timezone in database. If today's date in America is 14 march but in Asia it's 15 March. So if I retrieve today's object from Asia it's not showing anything because it is stored in American time which is 14 march and in Asia it's 15. So it is not showing anything. So how to use server time in views.py so that it will retrieve object based on server time no matter where you stay

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time in your views using the below

```
import datetime
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Moreover if you want to capture time depending on timezone, you can try the below

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

And you can have more information on timezone here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/